# Output JSON to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, wordpress

I am able to pull some data if I input the json manually into the JS...however, I am trying to pull it from a seperate file ('mindshare.json') and populate only certain fields (title, content, featured image).

When I use the code below, I get 3 columns of "undefined".

My question is, how do I:

1. Reference the ID of the post that will contain the title, content, image?
2. Do I have to add any other code to json file to call the nested tags?

Im a JSON noob, so I appreciate your patience.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var json = "mindshare.json";
  var tr;
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      tr = $('<tr/>');
      tr.append("<td>" + json[i].title + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + json[i].content + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + json[i].source + "</td>");
      $('.mindshare').append(tr);
  }
  });
  </script>
  <div class="mindshare">

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The JSON file can be found at http://toolboxwebdesign.com/mindshare.json.

Comment: Let me just note that the file name of a file isn't the same thing as that file's content.

Comment: Yea you're not opening the file. You will need `load()` or ajax for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://toolboxwebdesign.com/mindshare.json',      
    success: function(result){
        var json = JSON.stringify(result); 
        json = JSON.parse(json);
    }
});
```

Now you should have your JSON values in the `json` variable

*There are some cases in which the ajax call with the `json` datatype does not give a valid json and it should be parsed to a string and back again to object to work.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't seem to render anything....https://jsfiddle.net/toolbox3/u6qy7gz6/

Comment: its should be done like this https://jsfiddle.net/u6qy7gz6/3/ In your case the response would have arrived later that the code evaluation of the function

Comment: Hmm...still no luck.

Comment: also for this from jsfiddle the remote server should have CORS setup in order to make requests from other remotes

Comment: Are you making the ajax call from the same server?

Comment: Yes I am. the json is local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107160/discussion-between-toolbox3-and-sabbin).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you load the data from your json file and turn it into an HTML table :

```
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            row.append($('<td>'+cellData.title+'</td>'));
            row.append($('<td>'+cellData.content+'</td>'));
            row.append($('<td>'+cellData.source+'</td>'));
        });
        table.append(row);
    });
    return table;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://toolboxwebdesign.com/mindshare.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.mindshare').append(arrayToTable(data));
        }
    });
});
```

#### Notes

- You can't run AJAX calls locally. If you're running it on your laptop or desktop computer, you need to have a web server running.
- Your json file needs to be hosted at the same domain as your JS code.
- Your json needs to be valid. According to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), it is not!

Comment: @toolbox3 : Is your json file hosted at the same domain at your JS code?

Comment: Yes, its hosted in the root directory and its locally hosted where my test code is

Comment: @toolbox3 : You can't run AJAX calls locally. You need to run it on a web server.